# Plot Curve Function

Tags: r, rstudio

Why doesn't the red curve overlap the green `curve()`?

I noticed that it works without problems if operations are saved on intermediate objects and then we pass those objects to the `curve()` function. My interest is to understand why it doesn't work by doing the operation inside `curve()`. I found that curious.

```r
set.seed(1L)
x <- rnorm(n = 1e3L, mean = 200, sd = 30)
hist(x, probability = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 0.015))
curve(dnorm(x = x, mean = 200, sd = 30), col = "black", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # OK
curve(dnorm(x = x, mean = 199.6506, sd = 31.04748), col = "green", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # OK
curve(dnorm(x = x, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x)), col = "red", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # ?
```

Comment: This is because `curve` substitutes the x values into the expression. Rename your vector to anything not `x` and it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening is that the last plot is not using the values of

```
set.seed(1L)
x <- rnorm(n = 1e3L, mean = 200, sd = 30)

mean(x)
#[1] 199.6506
sd(x)
#[1] 31.04748
```

used in the green curve.
From the documentation of function `curve` (my emphasis):

> The function or expression expr (for curve) or function x (for plot)
>   is **evaluated at n points equally spaced over the range [from, to]**. The
>   points determined in this way are then plotted.
>
> If either from or to is NULL, it defaults to the corresponding element
>   of xlim if that is not NULL.
>
> What happens when neither from/to nor xlim specifies both x-limits is
>   a complex story. For plot() and for curve(add = FALSE) the
>   defaults are (0, 1). For curve(add = NA) and curve(add = TRUE) **the
>   defaults are taken from the x-limits used for the previous plot.** (This
>   differs from versions of R prior to 2.14.0.)

The following function shows what the documentation says. It outputs the values of `min(x)`, `max(x)` (the x-limits) and of `mean(x)` and `sd(x)` computed from the vector passed to the function.
The value `length.out = 101` below is the default `n = 101`.

```
xx <- seq(100, 320, length.out = 101)
mean(xx)
#[1] 210
sd(xx)
#[1] 64.46038


f <- function(x) {
  cat("Inside the function:\n")
  cat("min(x):", min(x), "\tmax(x):", max(x), "\n")
  cat("mean(x):", mean(x), "sd(x):", sd(x), "\n")
  dnorm(x, mean = mean(x), sd = sd(x))
}

hist(x, probability = TRUE, ylim = c(0, 0.015))
curve(dnorm(x = x, mean = 200, sd = 30), col = "black", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # OK
curve(dnorm(x = x, mean = 199.6506, sd = 31.04748), col = "green", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # OK

cat("Outside the function:\nmin(x):", min(x), "\tmax(x):", max(x), "\n\n")
#Outside the function:
#min(x): 109.7585   max(x): 314.3083 

curve(f(x), col = "red", lty = 1, lwd = 2, add = TRUE) # ?
#Inside the function:
#min(x): 100    max(x): 320 
#mean(x): 210 sd(x): 64.46038
```

These values are the ones expected, this is documented behaviour.
Finally, the plot.

[image]